# Pass to chromedriver capabilities as desiredCapabilities c#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I have software which does automated testing via chrome browser, but now this program failed with error message "Vector smash protection is enabled."
I've found a solution for this case, but this solution implemented via java API.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--incognito"));
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("test-type");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

How to implement a code the same as above via c#?

Answer (score 2):

You need a Dictionary

```
// Capabilities Values
var imageSetting = new Dictionary<string, object> {{"images", 2}};
var content =      new Dictionary<string, object> {{"profile.default_content_settings", imageSetting}};
var prefs =        new Dictionary<string, object> {{"prefs", content}};

// List of Chromium Command Line Switches 
var options = new ChromeOptions(); 
options.AddArguments( 
     "--disable-extensions", 
     "--disable-features", 
     "--disable-popup-blocking",
     "--disable-settings-window");

// Add the Capabilities
var field = options.GetType().GetField("additionalCapabilities", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
if (field != null)
{
     var dict = field.GetValue(options) as IDictionary<string, object>;
     if (dict != null) dict.Add(ChromeOptions.Capability, prefs);
}

// Create the Chrome Driver
var chromeDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Also you can send the driver path when you create the ChromeDriver object.